# Is there a relationship between the magnitude of the velocity and acceleration vector?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity, terminology

Given a path, how do the magnitude of the velocity and acceleration vector along the path correlate? I am confused due to the fact that the acceleration is the change of velocity over time and in general if you plot the velocity and acceleration over time, you can see a correlation (e.g. constant velocity means zero acceleration). So I expected the same relationship for the magnitude of the velocity and acceleration vector. Moreover, I got confused because the magnitude of a vector is always positive and in the general plots of the velocity and acceleration over time it is not the case (e.g. linear decrease in velocity means constant negative acceleration).

Therefore, can someone clarify if there is a clear relationship between the magnitudes of the velocity and acceleration vector and how this is defined? And if not, is there a relationship between the velocity and acceleration vector, so you can verify if your velocity and acceleration vector are correctly calculated?

Comment: *Is there a relationship between the velocity and acceleration vector?* $\mathbf a=d\mathbf v/dt$

Comment: Given what kind of a "path"?

Comment: The motion of a point particle along a path that is parametrized by the time t @BobD

Comment: So its a path of displacement vs time?

Answer (score 0):

> Given a path, how do the magnitude of the velocity and acceleration vector along the path correlate?

Assuming the path is parameterized by $t$ (that even more concretely can stand for time), the position vector is $\mathbf{r}(t)$, so as you may know, the velocity vector $\mathbf{v}(t)$ is given by:
$$ \mathbf{v}(t)=\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt}(t)\tag{1}$$
and the acceleration vector $\mathbf{a}(t)$ is given by:
$$ \mathbf{a}(t)=\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}(t)=\frac{d^2\mathbf{r}}{dt^2}(t)\tag{2}$$

Now to address your first question, the magnitude of any vector is given by the square root of its dot product with itself, applying this to equation $(2)$ we obtain:

$$ ||\mathbf{a}||=\sqrt{\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}}=\sqrt{\dot{\mathbf{v}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{v}}}=||\dot{\mathbf{v}}||\tag{3}$$

Where, for notational brevity I've used Newton's notation for time derivatives: $\dot{\mathbf{A}}\equiv\frac{d\mathbf{A}}{dt}$ and also dropped specifying the $t$ dependence explicitly.

So, in words: **the magnitude of the acceleration vector is equal to the magnitude of the time derivative of the velocity vector.**

Important confusion to avoid here, note that: $$\frac{d}{dt}\left|\left|\mathbf{v}\right|\right| \neq \left|\left|\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\right|\right| $$

The RHS is $||\dot{\mathbf{v}}||$ but not the LHS! In particular, the LHS *can* be negative because the magnitude of a vector can of course decrease in time, which will be reflected in the value of the time derivative. But the RHS is given by the norm of a vector, which is always non-negative. Most importantly, the LHS is *not* the magnitude of the acceleration vector $\mathbf{a}$.

> ... if you plot the velocity and acceleration over time, you can see a correlation (e.g. constant velocity means zero acceleration). So I expected the same relationship for the magnitude of the velocity and acceleration vector. Moreover, I got confused because the magnitude of a vector is always positive and in the general plots of the velocity and acceleration over time it is not the case

The plots you're mentioning are in fact **not** ones that describe the *magnitude* of the velocity and acceleration vectors as a function of time, because indeed the magnitudes of such (Euclidean) vectors is non-negative. More likely, you're thinking about plots for what can be called "signed speed" as a function of time, which are useful when we want to describe the motion in $1$ dimension. Indeed, such a single real value effectively describes a $1$-dimensional *vector*, where its sign is the vector's direction and its magnitude is simply the absolute value. However, for a general vector in $d$ dimensions its magnitude is defined by a non-negative scalar (its norm) which can be completely separated from its direction, so that one can always express any vector $\mathbf{A}$ as:

$$\mathbf{A} = ||\mathbf{A}||\hat{n}$$

Where $\hat{n}$ is the customary way to denote a unit vector pointing in a direction of interest. You can read off from the above that the direction of any such vector is given by dividing the vector by its magnitude.

> Therefore, can someone clarify if there is a clear relationship between the magnitudes of the velocity and acceleration vector and how this is defined?

Since you are emphasizing that your question is about magnitudes, I want to give you a kind of counterexample, to explain that really, knowing only the magnitude of either the velocity vector or of the acceleration vector, is not sufficient information to define the motion.

In [uniform circular motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Uniform_circular_motion) as you may know, at all times the velocity vector is perpendicular to the acceleration vector. A consequence of this is that the **magnitude** of the velocity vector doesn't change in time (Hint: to prove this calculate the time derivative of $\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}$ and recall what this quantity is).

In fact, you can make up all sorts of weird paths that a particle takes while having a fixed magnitude of its velocity vector, just by requiring that the acceleration vector is perpendicular to it at every instant, e.g. require $\mathbf{a}(t)\cdot\mathbf{v}(t)=0$ for all $t$. With that condition satisfied, the *magnitude* of the acceleration vector $||\mathbf{a}(t)||$ at each instant can vary wildly, but still it won't affect the magnitude of the velocity vector $||\mathbf{v}(t)||$ and you'll see the particle is making all kinds of twists and turns, not necessarily a simple circular motion, while maintaining a constant *speed*.

I hope this serves to give you an understanding that knowing only $||\mathbf{a}(t)||$ gives you no information about $||\mathbf{v}(t)||$ and also vice versa.

Comment: Clear! Two additional questions: 
1. So if I understand you correct the plots for what can be called "signed" speed and acceleration as a function of time, the velocity and acceleration vectors point to the same direction (i.e. lay on the same line) and the direction says something about the sign (for example left is negative and right is positive). If that's the case, I understood what you meant.

Comment: 2. How can you check if the velocity and acceleration vector are correctly calculated at each $t$? Is there a way to check this by means of a plot like the "signed" velocity and acceleration, so I can check if the velocity and acceleration vector are correctly calculated? So I don't only have the magnitude, but the whole vector of the velocity and acceleration.

Comment: @Math98 Re 1. Yes, it only makes sense to have a signed speed value or a signed acceleration value when describing motion in a *specific* direction. For example, If you are interested in studying only the $x$ component of the velocity and acceleration vectors of a particle moving in 3 dimensions, there's no problem looking only at $v_x(t)$ and $a_x(t)$, their values can be negative for some $t$ values and it makes perfect sense, it just means the $x$ component is directed along the negative $x$ axis.

Comment: @Math98 (1/2) Re 2. If the velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$ is given as an analytic, differentiable function of $t$ it simply comes down to making sure you're correctly differentiating it with respect to $t$, as indicated in equation $(2)$ of my answer.  Also, note that from what I replied to 1. at least in cartesian coordinates, you can still plot each component of acceleration and velocity separately and you will indeed find the correlations you were mentioning (e.g. $v_x$ will increase when $a_x$ is positive, $v_x$ stays constant when $a_x=0$ etc.).

Comment: (2/2) But note that this won't work if you plot the vector components as calculated with respect to coordinate systems with variable basis vectors, like polar coordinates (For example, if the motion is circular the radial acceleration $\mathbf{a}\cdot\hat{e}_r$ is always negative but the radial speed $\mathbf{v}\cdot\hat{e}_r$ remains $0$!).

Comment: As a response on (1/2) Re 2. The velocity vector $\mathbf{v}$ is always tangent to the path, so only has a tangential component, right? So do you need to decompose $\mathbf{v}$ according to the reference frame or to the path (normal and tangential direction) to find the correlations I was mentioning? I think the first one, because the second one makes no sense, as it says you don't have a normal velocity so never a normal acceleration, which doesn't make sense. Moreover, is there a relation between the tangential and normal direction to the path for the velocity and acceleration at each $t$?

Comment: @Math98 The velocity vector is always tangential to the path due to (from $(2)$): $$d\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{v}dt$$ If you only take the tangential component of the *acceleration* by calculating $$a_{\parallel} = \mathbf{a}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{v}||}$$ then this component of acceleration will correlate with the magnitude $||\mathbf{v}||$, including taking a negative value when it is opposite to the velocity vector's direction. Note that $||\mathbf{v}||$ will still be non negative, since there's no preferred "positive" or "negative" direction for a general path in 2 or more dimensions.

Comment: @Math98 Re: *"you don't have a normal velocity so never a normal acceleration"* -- This is incorrect. True, velocity is always tangential to the path. But acceleration can be in any direction with respect to the path, that's in virtue of the acceleration being the *second* time derivative of the position vector, so you can no longer do the little "differential trick" I did above and say the acceleration is always along the path ;-) This trick only works when to first approximation the relation is linear, e.g. $$\Delta{\mathbf{r}} = \mathbf{v}\Delta{t}$$

Comment: Clear, but my question was on: "at least in cartesian coordinates, you can still plot each component of acceleration and velocity separately and you will indeed find the correlations you were mentioning (e.g. $\textbf{v}_x$  will increase when $\textbf{a}_x$ is positive, $\textbf{v}_x$ stays constant when $\textbf{a}_x$=0  etc.)" Do you mean by this, 
it holds when decomposing the velocity and acceleration vector in the orientation of the two Cartesian axes (x and y)?

Comment: Moreover, in the derivation for the formula for $\textbf{a}_{||}$, if I understand correctly, you calculated first the unit vector (i.e. direction) of the velocity (as it is tangent to the path) and then multiplied with the acceleration vector to get the tangential acceleration vector.

Comment: @Math98 Yes the correlations will hold in cartesian coordinates for each separate pair of acceleration and velocity components. Btw you can also prove that $$a_{\parallel}=\frac{d||\mathbf{v}||}{dt}$$ -- the RHS leads to the same expression I wrote above. And yes, you got the idea right of how it is calculated.

Comment: Btw this expression is not a vector. It is a scalar value (dot product produces a scalar) for the projection of the acceleration vector along the direction of the velocity vector, hence it can be negative

Comment: Indeed, that expression $a_{||}$ I already knew, but good you're mentioning it. You're right, it should be a scalar and not a vector I'm realizing just now. Everything seems to be clear now, thanks! Btw any expressions for the normal acceleration, you know besides $a_{n} = \kappa||\mathbf{v}||$

Comment: $$\mathbf{a} = a_{\parallel}\frac{\mathbf{v}}{||\mathbf{v}||} +\mathbf{a}_{\perp}$$ You can read it off from this ;-) btw all of this is addressed in any standard mechanics textbook in a section on kinematics, you may want to pick up one and get all this info in a much more organized way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also view the problem this way:
Let the velocity vector be $$\vec{v}= v \hat{\eta}$$
Where $v$ is the magnitude of the velocity and $\hat{\eta}$ is an unit vector in the direction of motion. Note,in general, both $v$ and $\hat{\eta}$ will change over time. Acceleration can then be written as
$$
\begin{align}
 \vec{a} &= \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\\
&= \frac{d}{dt} v\hat{\eta} \\
&= \frac{dv}{dt} \hat{\eta} + v\frac{d\hat{\eta}}{dt}
\end{align}
$$
The first term in the acceleration vector is $\frac{dv}{dt} \hat{\eta}$. It says that  component of acceleration along the velocity vector, at any moment, is equal to the change rate of magnitude of the velocity evaluated at that moment.

However, that's not all. There is another component of acceleration vector, $v\frac{d\hat{\eta}}{dt}$. Change rate of the direction of velocity, $\frac{d\hat{\eta}}{dt}$, in general doesn't have any obvious relations of magnitude of the velocity.